# How to search for an element within a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays

I'd like to ask on how do I check whether my 2D array against a string for duplicate value ?

```
//2d array
sudokuBoard=[[0 for sudokuRow in range(0,int(boardSize))] for sudokuColumn in range(0,int(boardSize))]
```

The 2D array will produce a 3x3 table like the following :

```
0|0|0
0|0|0
0|0|0
```

How do I ensure that when i enter a value into the table above, it will check the value position row and column for duplicate value ?

For example, if i enter a "0" into the table there will be an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to access to your columns , so you can do that job with `zip(*sudokuBoard)` then for insert a value , you must check for existence the value in a proper row and column ! Note that you have your rows in `sudokuColumn` !

```
columns=map(list,zip(*sudokuBoard))
sudokuBoard=[[0 for sudokuRow in range(0,int(boardSize))] for sudokuColumn in range(0,int(boardSize))]

def insert_value(your_list,value,row,col):
  if value not in columns[col] and value not in your_list[row]:
      your_list[row][col]=value
  else:
      raise ValueError("you can not insert a duplicate value !!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def inBoard(value):
    for row in sudokuBoard:
        if value in row:
            return True
    return False
```

With this you can do something like this:

```
if inBoard(3):
    print "already in board"
else:
    print "well played"
```